# Why is the textbox in my ASP.NET webform always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is my markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/User/Default.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Consulation.aspx.cs" Inherits="PetShop.User.Consulation" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var second = 5;
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("<%=lblMsg.ClientID%>").style.display = "none";
            }, second * 1000)
        }
    </script>
    <link href="../CSSandJS/StyleCss/consulation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


    <!-- Slider -->
    <section id="Slider">
        <div class="aspect-ratio-169">
            <img src="../CSSandJS/images/bg_1.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="../CSSandJS/images/bg_2.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="../CSSandJS/images/bg_3.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="../CSSandJS/images/bg_4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="dot-container">
            <div class="dot active"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End Slider -->


    <!-- Free Consulation -->
    <section class="contact">
        <div class="container-contact">
            <h1>Đặt lịch hẹn</h1>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="contact-img">
                    <img src="../CSSandJS/images/bg_1.jpg" alt="" width="400">
                </div>

                <div class="input-infor">
                    <div class="form">
                        <div class="dbl-field">

                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" CssClass="form-control option field-mail listOp" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="TENDV" DataValueField="MADV" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Chọn danh mục</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>

                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cs %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [MADV], [TENDV] FROM [DICHVU]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                        </div>

                        <div class="dbl-field">
                            <div class="field-mail">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input" placeholder="Nhập email" required></asp:TextBox>
                                <i class="ri-mail-line"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="dbl-field">
                            <div class="field">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNameAcc" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input" placeholder="Nhập tên"></asp:TextBox>
                                <i class="ri-user-line"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="field">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSDT" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input" placeholder="Nhập số điện thoại" MaxLength="11"></asp:TextBox>
                                <i class="ri-phone-line"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="dbl-field">
                            <div class="field">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNgay" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
                                <i class="ri-calendar-2-line"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="field">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTime" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input" placeholder="Nhập giờ hẹn" MaxLength="5" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                <i class="ri-time-line"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="message">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" CssClass="form-control textarea" placeholder="Tin nhắn" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                            <i class="ri-message-2-line"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="button-area">
                            <asp:Button ID="Add" runat="server" Text="Gửi lịch hẹn" class="btn btn-primary button" OnClick="Add_Click"/>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                            <%--<asp:linkbutton id="submitcal" runat="server" cssclass="btn btn-primary button" OnClick="Add_Click">gửi lịch hẹn</asp:linkbutton>--%>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End Free Consulation -->


</asp:Content>
```

The textbox doesn't get any value when I debug the program.

I have tested the stored procedure in SQL Server and it works fine. But the data returned from the SQL code is empty.

My button submit code:

```
namespace PetShop.User
{
    public partial class Consulation : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void clear()
        {
            txtEmail.Text = string.Empty;
            txtDescription.Text = string.Empty;
            txtNameAcc.Text = string.Empty;
            txtSDT.Text = string.Empty;
            txtNgay.Text = string.Empty;
            txtTime.Text = string.Empty;
            ddlCategory.ClearSelection();
        }

        protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string actionName = string.Empty;
            bool isValidToExcute = true;

            con = new SqlConnection(Connection.GetConnectionString());
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Add_KHaddLH", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "INSERT4KH");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaDv", ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMail", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ten", txtNameAcc.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sdt", txtSDT.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NgayHen", txtNgay.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GioHen", txtTime.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GhiC", txtDescription.Text.Trim());


            if (isValidToExcute)
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    actionName = "gửi";
                    lblMsg.Visible = true;
                    lblMsg.Text = "Lịch hẹn " + actionName + " thành công!";
                    lblMsg.CssClass = "alert alert-success";
                    clear();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblMsg.Visible = true;
                    lblMsg.Text = "Lỗi !!!" + ex.Message;
                    lblMsg.CssClass = "alert alert-danger";
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think the error lies in the page reload, because when submitting it will delete all the data in the textbox and then enter.

I've tried adding some commands to the button but still can't handle that it keeps losing textbox data.

I update code behind and markup.

Support me,

Thank.

Comment: Which text box does not have a value? I see ONLY 2 text boxes in above markup, that of txtNgay, and that of txtTime. Yet your code behind has a whole bunch more text boxes? Where are they, and show the markup for those other text boxes. And if if you have a page load event that fills out some of these text boxes, then include that code. We don't need all your code, but you telling us some text box values don't have a value, and THEN FOR SOME CRAZY reason you don't show the markup for those text boxes, why would you make us play a guessing game here?

Comment: I also suggest you REMOVE the UseSubmitBehavior="false" (I mean, UNLESS you have REALLY good reason for messing with this setting? You need to give a REALLY great explain as to why your using that option. You are better off to remove that setting, since it places js code in the markup for the submit - and I am betting you have some messay JavaScript code that not working - so remove that option, and in place of js code being used (and injected) to submit, it will use the built in browser submit.

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal There are 2 things I need to explain more about the code above:
Firstly, because the code is quite long, I just let txtTime and txtRight represent.

Comment: There are 2 things I need to explain more about the code above:
Firstly, because the code is quite long, I just let txtTime and txtRight represent.
Second, I'm trying with the textbox when I press submit with UseSubmitBehavior="false" it works, if I remove it, it can't send or work at all.

Comment: Well, that is a BIG issue that the button don't work - and that is valauble informaiton!!! --- it should work!!! - so now we have another issue and problem to deal with!!! As for the code behind long? I already stated you don't need to post all of the code, but you need to provide more --- at the VERY least the controls and parts involved in the markup. So, yes, we do need to see the markup of those other controls unless you want to play more guessing games.  That button should work, but perhaps BIG THINGS the size of Mount Everest are being left out here - say like a update panel used here?

Comment: Also, what does page load do? Remember, for each and every button click, page load fires again and again each time - and will run BEFORE your button code stub runs. So, if you have code in page load to setup controls, load controls and data, then such code that often sets up values will run each time and thus will overwrite what the user types in. As a reuslt, 99% of your pages will need to have a if (!IsPostBack) stub in that page load. But, as I stated and asked multiple times - we need more code and a re-producible example, else we are playing darts in a room with the lights out to help.

Comment: I have updated all my code, hope anyone can help. Because when I click submit button, the page reloads without losing data from the textbox. @AlbertD. Kallal

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so that helps a boatload.

if we have this code:

```
    protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string actionName = string.Empty;
        bool isValidToExcute = true;

        Debug.Print(txtEmail.Text);
```

output:

[image]

So, you might want to put a break point in, or simple add some debug.prints, and see which text box controls are "empty". But, just looking at what you have, those text boxes should be ok.

And including page-load, shows that you not say running the "clear" routine you have. (so, having included the page load event eliminates about 100 possible issues here. This is VERY much why posting some of your code allows the public here to eliminate a 100 "back and forth" suggestions.) So, for example, had you included "clear" routine in page load, then of course page load fires each and every time BEFORE a button click event, so code in page load is VERY OFTEN suspect here. But, since you don't have code in page load event, we scratch that off the table.

So, far, the controls look to have values, but I suggest you add a break point, or some debug.prints as per above to be 100% sure that the controls in fact do not have values.

Also, just pasting in some of the markup, we see things like this:

[image]

So, you do have stray "garbage" in a number of places. (not good).

As it stands, with the posted markup, I MOST certainly do get/see/have/enjoy/observe that the text boxes are intact, do have values.

Given we can't re-produce your issue?

I suggest creating a blank new page, drop in some of those controls, and try a test button - (don't even bother with the database save code - we NOT gone that far down the debugging road just yet).

So, only thing so far?

Are you 100% sure the text boxes don't have values, and you tested this BEFORE any of the database save code runs?

and do remove the stray "required" markup in that txtEmail box, the editor even HONKS OUT AT YOU that the markup is bad as per above screen shot.

In fact, drop in another button on the form, and its only job would be to debug print out the text boxes - does that work?

As it stands now, you don't have a re-producable error, and the community in general here has not, does not see your error, nor are we the viewing public EVEN able to re-produce that these text boxes don't have values.

As a result, there information we don't have to re-produce the error.

I suggest building a page with just the txtEmail that is blank, and a simple button. if that works, then start adding markup from that other page until it stops working, since we here can't re-produce your issue with the provided code and markup you have provided.

And, since you using a master page, then check if page load in master page has any code that runs on page load.

Comment: The problem here is that it always reloads the page, losing all the value of the textbox and the drop list always returns empty and 0, so how should I handle it.

Comment: It would/should only lose the drop list if you have code in the page load that is loading the ddl list. But, in your posted code, you don't share what the page load event does, and if that page load event loads up controls, or clears them, that that's the simple issue here. The WHOLE POINT of posting some code is to include these parts! So, is there code in the page load event that you left out??? What does it do? all pages re-load on button clicks, but it is a question then of making sure the page load event does not clear out, or overwrite what the user enters.

Comment: Page load not code.And the ddl part I added myself with datasource not code. Finally I can't get data from my own textbox.

Comment: Well, exactly, I noted the page load issue. However, had you posted code (showing that you don't have a page load event), then I would not have to ask that question. (see how this works!!!!). Again, 100's of assumptions have to be made here. And to be fair, 9 out 10 times, it is code in page load that causes this issue, but now we eliminated that!. As noted, I can't re-produce your issue, so you need to drop a button and text box on a new page, and reproduce the issue. We here are not able to re-produce your issue, so build a page with the one text box and a button - does  text box value show?

Comment: So, create a new blank page, and create a simple text box, and button click. You NEED to post a re-producible example here. Also, did you remove the stay required from the text box as instructed?

Comment: So I tried on the home page linked to the master page and the textbox in the search still works fine, because it still receives the value.But in the consulation page, the textboxes in the form are not working. So what's the fault?

Comment: We don't have your computer and software in front of us. And WORSE we have to ask for information for troubleshooting multiple times. Create a new page MyTest (with master page). Drop in controls, and a simple button to click. Test if email textbox retains it value. Then start adding more and more from that existing page, and you should reach a point in which it starts to fail. That's about the only way here. The other idea? Call your mother, tell her you going to take up truck driving school, or cooking school or something else, since its too much pulling teeth asking for information from you

Comment: I created a new page not linked to the masterpage and it worked even the button. Textbox got the value, and now what should I do.

Comment: I created a test page and linked to the masterpage, dropped a button + 2 textbox, it happened that it couldn't get the value of the textbox. It's completely empty textbox

Comment: Ok, so it looks like then something in the master page is at fault here. And it looks like your master page has 2 content areas. Does this simple text box and button fail when code is placed in either content area, or just the 2nd content area? So edit your post, and show the 2nd example of a simple button + text box that fails (should be VERY little markup). And try that markup as a test in either markup area (content 1 and content 2 area). So, now, if a simple text box and button fails, we have to start looking at master page.

Comment: I was able to fix the error of the textbox because in the main masterpage, 2 form actions were removed, so it didn't work, leading to the error.

Comment: Fantastic. It can be really hard, really frustrating. But, by sticking with this, chopping it down into smaller and smaller bits and parts? It looks like you found a issue in the master page. And this again points towards you posting markup. So, for example, when you started posting markup, then everyone here ALSO then could realize that a master page is being used - and once again, that helps, and points out another dozen possible issues. How this process works? It not magic, it just step by step. But, we eliminated page load, then you went to work on master page, and found the issue.